# convert JSON object to a different one

Tags: javascript, json

i have this json:

```
 [
  {
    "AF28110": 33456.75,
    "AF27989": 13297.26
  }
]
```

and i want to convert it to:

```
[ 
 { "name": "AF28110", "price": 33456.75},
 { "name": "AF27989", "price": 13297.26}
]
```

I have tried various making it with .map() but i cannot make it work.

does anyone have any idea how to do this?
thank you

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can try following code:

```
let output = [];
input.forEach(obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(key => output.push({name: key, price: obj[key]})))
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will give you names of your properties and then you can transform each name to a separate output array item.

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "AF28110": 33456.75,
    "AF27989": 13297.26
  }
]

const out = Object.keys(data[0]).map(el => {
  return { name: el, price: data[0][el] };
});

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `concat`, `Object.keys`, and `map`. You can take each item from the array, get the keys from that object, and then map each key to the name/price object you want. Do that for each item, then flatten the result (using concat).

Example:

```js
const arr = [{
  "AF28110": 33456.75,
  "AF27989": 13297.26
}]

const result = [].concat(...arr.map(o => Object.keys(o).map(k => ({name: k, price: o[k]}))))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple objects on the array, you can use `reduce`

```js
let arr = [
  {"AF28110": 33456.75,"AF27989": 13297.26},
  {"AF28111": 33456.20,"AF27984": 13297.88}
];

let result = arr.reduce((c, v) => c.concat(Object.entries(v).map(o => {return {name: o[0],price: o[1]}})), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var text = '[{"AF28110": 33456.75,"AF27989": 13297.26}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
 var keys = Object.keys(obj[i]);
 for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
    result[j] = '{ "name":' +keys[j] + ', "price":' + obj[i][keys[j]]+'}';
 } 
}
console.log(result);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Ways to achieve :**

- Using `Object.keys` method **:**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "AF28110": 33456.75,
    "AF27989": 13297.26
  }
];

var res = Object.keys(jsonObj[0]).map(item => {
  return {"name": item, "price": jsonObj[0][item] };
});

console.log(res);
```

- Using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` method **:**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "AF28110": 33456.75,
    "AF27989": 13297.26
  }
];

var res = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonObj[0]).map(item => {
  return {"name": item, "price": jsonObj[0][item] };
});

console.log(res);
```